# What is the correct way to PUT a complex entity type in MVC Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, put

I am sending a json request to my ProductController through Angularjs $resource using method PUT.
Product is recieved successfully. Problem is updating the complex properties of the product. 
Here is the product model.

```
 Product{
    //other properties
    public virtual List<Bookmark> Bookmarks { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ProductCounter> Counters { get; set; }
 }
```

Now here is my PUT method of the controller.

```
 public HttpResponseMessage PutProduct(int key, Product product)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }

        if (key != product.ID)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        product.ProductDocuments.Clear();
        var counters = new List<ProductCounter>(product.Counters);
        product.Counters.Clear();
        foreach (var counter in counters)
        {
            product.Counters.Add(counter);
            db.Entry(counter).State = EntityState.Added;

        }
        db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

If I remove the foreach block, all counters are deleted.

If I add the foreach block, if product contains any counters they are all duplicated. 2 counters in product will become 4 and so on. What is the problem? even I am cloning the list of counters but dont know why clear without foreach works and with foreach cleared counters come back again. Even I tried setting ID to 0 of counters in foreach but that also duplicated the records.

I have tried this version of foreach after counters.clear();

```
  foreach (var counter in counters)
        {
            product.Counters.Add(new ProductCounter(){Name=counter.Name,Value=counter.Value});
        }
```

this gives this error in response :

> ""innererror":{
>         "message":"An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The
>   EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot
>   be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions
>   while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in
>   your entity types. See the InnerException for details.
>
> "internalexception":{
>           "message":"Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or
>   deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager
>   entries.","type":"System.Data.Entity.Core.OptimisticConcurrencyException","stacktrace":"
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions
>   options)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()"

Here is the POST method, for more information. Counters are actually added anew to a product and other complex properties like Documents and ProjectTasks have relationship.

```
 // POST api/Product
    public HttpResponseMessage PostProduct(Product product)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Products.Add(product);
            foreach (var projectTask in product.ProjectTasks)
            {
                db.ProjectTasks.Attach(projectTask);
            }
            foreach (var bookmark in product.Bookmarks)
            {
                db.Bookmarks.Attach(bookmark);
            }
            foreach (var document in product.ProductDocuments)
            {
                db.Documents.Attach(document);
            }
            //No attachment for counters, they are added as a list. if I remove all attachments for other entities, these entities get duplicated in their own tables.


            db.SaveChanges();

            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, product);
            //response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { key = product.ID }));
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }
    }
```

**Question**:
**I want to keep only coming counters and no more existing. Whether it is done through first clearing all and then adding new comers? or any other method?**

Comment: You really should use models in MVC and not expose entities to the views. Do your copy logic from the model to the entity inside the controller and use a business- and/or data layer for handeling your entities.

Comment: I would imaging that your second approach should have worked though. Do you have primary keys and foreign keys set appropriately? Are you perhaps clearing the collection, then adding new items without saving the changes in between, leading to a collision in the interim?

Comment: This is all what you see. should I show the other entities here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/858757/silvermind I am learning about your suggestion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/400547/jon-hanna How can I save the state in between. using db.savechanges() ?

Answer (score 0):

After your savechanges() you should use.This one worked for me

```
db.Entry(projectTask).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

Comment: after your save change